# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

i am trying this code

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

from lsd import *

import cv2

im = cv2.imread('/home/lenovo/Downloads/python-lsd-master/test_data/chairs.pgm')

#fullName = '1.jpg'

folder, imgName = os.path.split(im)

src = cv2.imread(im, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

lines =lsd.__module__

#path1=os.path.normpath('/home/lenovo/pylsd/example/751626ntl.txt')

for i in range(lines.shape[0]):

    pt1 = (int(lines[i, 0]), int(lines[i, 1]))

    pt2 = (int(lines[i, 2]), int(lines[i, 3]))

    width = lines[i, 4]

    cv2.line(src, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), int(np.ceil(width / 2)))

cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder, 'cv2_' + imgName.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'), src)
```

> ValueError: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray

could you please help

Comment: Please format your message

Answer (score 0):

If using Jupyter Notebooks, for codes like this you can run the cell only once. If you have to run the cell again, load the image data again before that. It actually worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30475934)